# Error para enviar correos con datos de usuario con Laravel: "Type error: Argument 1 passed to Month::__construct()"

Tags: laravel, mailer

Me sale el siguiente error al intentar enviar un correo con Laravel:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Mail\AnalystMonth::__construct() must be an instance of App\Mail\DataUser, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection given, called in C:\wamp\www\intranet\intranet\app\Http\Controllers\AnalystController.php on line 37

Mi clase Mailer

```
class AnalystMonth extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $dataUser;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(DataUser $dataUser)
    {
        $this->dataUser = $dataUser;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('mails.analystMonth');
    }
}
```

Mi funcion del controlador que enviar el email

```
public function choiceAnalyst(Request $request){

   $file = $request->file('document');
   $userSelect = $request->input('user');
   $data = User::where('id', '=', $userSelect)->get();

   \Mail::to('eaquino@spi.com.ve')->send(new AnalystMonth($data));

}
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionar el error? Sé que el error se encuentra en la parte que quiero cargar los datos para pasarlos a la vista, porque si quito esas lineas de código, el correo llega sin problema.

Comment: Esa clase `DataUser` es una clase creada por vos? extiende de la clase `User`? si ese es el caso deberias cambiar el get() que usas al final cuando buscas el usuario y lo guardas en data por un first(), ya que get te trae una collection y ese es el error que te esta marcando, en cambio first te trae el usuario directamente.

Comment: `DataUser` no es una clase, ya me di cuenta que tengo que instanciar es una clase, la cambie por mi clase de `User`, ya envia el correo, pero llega vacio, como si no estuviera pasando ningun dato

Comment: Podrías poner como te quedo el código con los cambios que realizaste y la vista que renderiza el mail también, para que podamos echarle un vistazo.

Comment: No listo hermano, el problema es que trataba de sacar los datos con un `foreach` como si me estuviera enviando muchos, con un simple `{{$user->name}}`, ya me da lo que necesito, muchas gracias. Si quieres publica la respuesta para seleccionarla como correcta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya que llegamos a cual era el inconveniente en los comentarios la agrego como respuesta.

El error en cuestion es:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Mail\AnalystMonth::__construct()
>   must be an instance of App\Mail\DataUser, instance of
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection given, called in
>   C:\wamp\www\intranet\intranet\app\Http\Controllers\AnalystController.php
>   on line 37

Que "traducido" dice algo así como que el constructor de la clase AnalystMonth espera un objeto de clase DataUser (creo que finalmente la cambiaste por User) pero esta recibiendo una Colleccion.

La solución seria reemplazar el `->get()` por un `->first()` al momento de traer el usuario, ya que `get()` trae una colleccion de usuarios, en este caso una colleccion con un solo usuario dentro y `first()` devuelve el objeto usuario directamente.

```
$data = User::where('id', '=', $userSelect)->first(); //cambio de get() por first()
```

Saludos!